# Twitter bootstrap : Expand with span12 on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my project.

It is the structure i am following to design layout-

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="expand-this">
<div class="span8">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6 pull-left">
<b>Display Name</b>
</div>
<div class="span6 pull-right">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hide-accordion">
<div class="span4">
<div class="block">
...some information..
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="button-hiding"></button>
```

Here you can see i am aligning two block in a row. Second span in `row-fluid` with `span4` Is taking dynamic values.
So i am trying to hide it with button.

**jQuery-**

```
$('.hide-accordion').hide();
$(function () {
    $('.button-hiding').click(function () {
        $('.hide-accordion').toggle(this);
    });
});
```

This is what working fine.
I am hiding this accordion on window load.

**What i want-**

I want span8 to take full width with `span12` when accordion is hidden and as soon as i click on button, accordion appears. then it should be taking original `span8` width.

I tried this too with jQuery-

```
$('.hide-accordion').hide();
$(function () {
    $('.button-hiding').click(function () {
        $('.hide-accordion').toggle(this);
        $('.Expand-this>div .span8').removeClass('span8');
        $(this).addClass('span12');
    });
});
```

But no luck, help?

Comment: Could you indent properly your HTML code please? Note that there is some code missing (the button code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

HTML:-

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 expand-this">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6 pull-left">
                <b>Display Name</b>
            </div>
            <div class="span6 pull-right">
                <input type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 hide-accordion">
        <div class="block">
            ...some information..
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="button-hiding"></button>
```

And Jquery:-

```
$(function () {
    $('.hide-accordion').hide();
    $(".expand-this").removeClass("span8").addClass("span12")
    $('.button-hiding').click(function () {
        if($(".expand-this").hasClass('span8')){
            $(".expand-this").removeClass("span8").addClass("span12")
        }else{
            $(".expand-this").removeClass("span12").addClass("span8")
        }
        $('.hide-accordion').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Manoz : Please mark the answer 'correct', if it has solved your Issue.